# Summing a column to a certain value

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with 2 variables, and 177 observations. I would like to sum up one variable to a certain value, and then get the value of the other variable when that threshold is reached. I will try to add an reproducible example. I am new here so forgive me if I do it wrong.

```
> df <- data.frame(x=10:1,y=1:10)
> print(df)
    x  y
1  10  1
2   9  2
3   8  3
4   7  4
5   6  5
6   5  6
7   4  7
8   3  8
9   2  9
10  1 10
```

How can I sum column `y` until it reaches a certain value, let's say `7`, and then either have it return the value of `X(4)`, or the row number `7`. I am sure it is pretty straightforward, but I seem to be drawing a blank.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  Do you want to only return the index number of y==7

Comment: check out `df$z <- cumsum(df$y)`

Comment: I am sorry I messed up that explanation. I want to sum y to a certain value. Let me try this again. Say I want to sum y until it reaches a value of 10. So that would be the 1st 4 observations of y(1+2+3+4). Then I want to be able to stop summing and somehow figure out what x is when the sum of y =10. Which in this case it would be 7.

Comment: I think I was confused by your post earlier.  I thought you want to sum `y` until the value of `y` in that column is `7`.

Comment: I can understand that. I messed up my example. Sorry about that it was my fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP just asked for the relevant value of x which would be done using:

```
df$x[which(cumsum(df$y) >= 10)[1]]
```

Also note this finds the first where cumsum(df$y) is at least 10 whereas the other answers find the last <= 7 which is potentially different (though not for this dataset). For the original question (pre-comment) it would need to be:

```
df$x[which(cumsum(df$y) > 7)[1]]
```

Comment: Perfect. This solution is returning the value of x which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.

```
df[cumsum(df$y) <= 7,]
   x y
1 10 1
2  9 2
3  8 3
```

Comment: I know the answer has been accepted, but it seems like `df[cumsum(df$y) > 7,][1,]` is more in line with the question

Comment: @Chris The question is been edited. My solution was for, what I think it was, to show the part of the df where the sum of 7 was not bigger than 7. At this point I have to admit that numbers 7 and then 10 have confused me. Maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion SabDem. Your solution works to but then there is a few extra steps to get the value of x. I am sorry for the confusion. Next time I ask a question I will make sure my example is better stated so you guys don't have to guess at what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Ennyization do not worry :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with base R, try this

```
> df$x[df$y >= 7][1]
[1] 4
> max(cumsum(df$y[df$y <= 7]))
[1] 28
```

Or if you need this in a matrix form:

```
> cbind(df$x[df$y >= 7][1], max(cumsum(df$y[df$y <= 7])))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4   28
```

I would still look into switching to `data.table` or at least `dplyr` packages for data manipulation.